# Difference Between Combining Quaternion Rotations and Rotation Matrices

Tags: matrix, rotation, quaternions

Is the result of combining two quaternion rotations the same as that of two matrices and then converting that into a quaternion?

I have a quaternion (q1) and rotation matrix (m2) as input for a function (unfortunately non-negotiable) and would like to rotate the initial quaternion by the matrix resulting in a new quaternion. I have tried a fair few ways of doing this and have slightly bizarre results.

If I convert q1 into a matrix (m1), calculate m2.m1 and convert the result into a quaternion I get what is a likely quaternion result. However if I convert m2 into a quaternion using the exact same function and multiply those together (in both orders, I know it's non-commutative) I get something entirely different. I would like to realise the quaternion combination so that I can eventually SLERP from the current quaternion to the result.

All functions have come from here: http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/index.htm and are being implemented in c++ and mathematica to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an exact correspondence between 3x3 rotation matrices and unit quarternions, up to a sign change in the quarternion (the sign is irrelevant when in comes to performing rotation on 3D vectors).

This means that given two quarternions, `q1`, `q2`, and their corresponding matrices, `m1`, `m2`, the action of the quarternions on a vector `v` is the same as the action of the matrices on `v`:

```
q2*(q1*v*(q1^-1))*(q2^-1) = m2*m1*v
```

If your program does not achieve this result with an arbitrary vector `v`, there is likely an error in your formula somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris. That equation is actually very helpful for testing my functions. I think my issue was slightly more fundamental (down to the handedness of my matrices) but this very much helped me spot that. Thanks again.